# 3d-Integral with residue method

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to deal with angular dependency $\theta_{kr}$ in the attempt to calculate this integral:

$$\int \frac{\mathrm {d^3} k}{(2 \pi)^3}  \frac{e^{i \vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}}{a-k^2+ib}$$

by residue method?

Comment: You can get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\vec k\cdot\vec r}}{a-k^2+\mathrm ib}
&=
\frac{2\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty k^2\mathrm dk\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikr\cos\theta}}{a-k^2+\mathrm ib}
\\
&=
\frac{2\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty\mathrm dk\frac{k^2}{\mathrm ikr}\frac{\left[\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikr\cos\theta}\right]_{-1}^1}{a-k^2+\mathrm ib}
\\
&=
\frac1{(2\pi)^2}\frac1{\mathrm ir}\int_0^\infty\mathrm dk\,k\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikr}-\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ikr}}{a-k^2+\mathrm ib}\;.
\\
&=
\frac1{(2\pi)^2}\frac1{2\mathrm ir}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dk\,k\frac{\mathrm e^{\mathrm ikr}-\mathrm e^{-\mathrm ikr}}{a-k^2+\mathrm ib}\;.\end{align}